# Quantization of the Gibbs distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantization

Consider a simple quantum mechanical system, for example, the 1d harmonic oscillator.

Given the inverse temperature $\beta$, the classical Gibbs distribution is the following function over the phase space (up to some normalization coefficient):
$$ \rho_{\beta}(x, p) = e^{- \beta H(x, p)}. $$

The Weyl quantization map $Q$ maps functions over the phase space to quantum operators.

If we try to quantize the Gibbs distribution using $Q$, we will arrive at the wrong answer:
$$ Q(\rho) = Q(e^{- \beta H}), $$
while the right answer is
$$ e^{- \beta Q(H)} \neq Q(e^{- \beta H}). $$
(for details see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/664471/30833) and the link to the Wigner's paper mentioned therein).

My question is: what are the physical reasons to prefer $e^{- \beta Q(H)}$ over $Q(e^{- \beta H})$?